# Linear map of extrem points and its injectivity, surjectivity

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, convex-analysis, linear-transformations

Before entering my problem, let me review some related results:

Suppose $\mathcal{S}$ is a  convex hull of finite points: $\mathcal{S}= \operatorname{conv}(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_m)$, then

1. By "[Convex hull of extreme points](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/282036/convex-hull-of-extreme-points)" , we know $\mathcal{S}$ is the convex hull of its extreme points, which is the subset of $\{x_1,\ldots, x_m\}$.
2. By "[preservation of extreme points under linear transformation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1591561/preservation-of-extreme-points-under-linear-transformation)", if the transformation is linear, let $A$ = {the extreme points of the image of a compact convex set}, then the **preimage** of $A$ must be the extreme points of that compact convex set. But the **inverse** in not true. The inverse is true only under such transformation 
   is injective and surjective.

My question is:

Suppose

1. We have two sets $A,B$ with $L: A\rightarrow B$, which is **linear**.
2. $A,B$ are both convex, compact and both sets have at least one extreme point.
3. Suppose $L$ maps **extreme points** in $A$ **one-to-one and onto** to **extreme points** in $B$.

So obviously, $A$ and $B$ are convex hull of their extreme points.

Question: Is $L$ a one-to-one and onto linear map for $A\rightarrow B$?

If not, could you please provide an counter-example?

Comment: Are $A$ and $B$ generic convex sets, or are they (or at least one of them), like $\mathcal{S}$, the convex hull of a finite number of points?

Comment: @Fimpellizieri Actually $A,B$ are convex hull of infinitely number of points. For example, $A=SO(2)$, ie $2\times 2$ rotation matrices with $0\leq \theta \leq 2\pi$. $B$ is a set of rank $1$, $2\times 2$ positive semidefinite matrices with trace one. So $B$ can be built by $vv^T$ with $v_1^2+v_2^2=1$.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri Does your question make any subtle difference in the answer?

Comment: It is better if the answer is general. Since I have no idea if it makes any crucial difference if number of extreme points is finite, or infinite.

Comment: I was thinking about simple cases (polytopes) first, looks more tractable. I don't have an answer yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the assertion is false.

Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ be a tetrahedron and let $L$ be a projection onto a two-dimensional subspace, such that $B = L\,A$ is a quadrangle.